# Laravel PHP queue:work not working on linux

Tags: linux, laravel

I tried to use supervisor and this is my config:
[image]

Status

[image]

In my job table 
[image]

Also the "tries=3" is not working and my worker.log is also null

Answer (score 0):

The jobs in your table are in the 'default' queue, but you've told your workers to only process jobs from the 'jobs' queue.

In the supervisor config either remove --queue=jobs entirely, or change it to --queue=default

Comment: Did you remember to make supervisor reread the config and restart everything?